# ¿Cómo subir una aplicación web en un servidor gratuito?

Tags: java, jsf, aplicación-web, tomcat, glassfish

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en JavaWeb(jdk 1.7) con ICEFACES y conexión a una base de datos mySQL. He estado probándola localmente con GlassFish y Tomcat y todo funciona perfecto, pero he intentado subirla a servidores gratuitos como 260mb.net y 000webhost.com para probar pero sucede que al desempaquetar el archivo WAR que se me genera e intentar acceder a mi aplicación me muestra solamente la parte html de mi código, y no muestra lo que esta escrito en xhtml. ¿Qué problemas puedo tener?

Actualmente estoy trabajando con tomcat 7.0, al momento de subir el archivo WAR y de inciar me sale el siguiente error:

FALLO - No se pudo arrancar la aplicación en trayectoria de contexto /SoftwareSJRApacheTomcat
FALLO - Encontrada excepción org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SoftwareSJRApacheTomcat]]

Estoy utilizando este servidor de aplicaciones gratuito, que al parecer soporta java y j2ee: http://s156.eatj.com/index.jsp

Comment: Tienes acceso al log, probablemente falte algo

Comment: Página de inicio de `000webhost.com`: "Zero cost website hosting with PHP, MySQL, Cpanel & no ads". El otro servidor tampoco indica por ninguna parte que de soporte a Java... Busca un servidor que ofrezca hosting para Java (la verdad que no hay muchos, con PHP es más fácil controlar los recursos de cada usuario).

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses `x10hosting`, instala Apache _TomEE_ o _Tomcat_ como normalmente lo harías en otro servidor y sube el .war a tu directorio, después instala el _WAR_ a través de la consola de _Apache_. Yo lo he probado y funciona bastante bien para ser gratuito.

Comment: @DavidBrito Te invito a ponerte del lado de alguien que intente ayudar a resolver tu problema. ¿No crees que podrías brindar más información de tu ambiente, qué intentaste, qué está sucediendo, dónde se genera el error, cuándo...?

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate de haber desplegado correctamente tu aplicación en un servidor de aplicaciones compatible con J2EE. Por lo que comentas parece que su aplicación está en un servidor web, por eso sólo puedes ver el contenido estático.

Answer (score 1):

para poder publicar una aplicaciòn web java, debes asegurarte que el servidor de aplicaciones soporte tecnologias java, esto porque una aplicacion web java, se puede componer por JSP, XHTML, JS, bytecode de java, etc, servidores como tomcat, weblogic, WAS, soportan aplicaciones en java, es por eso que puedes desplegar sin problema, si quieres probar un Paas, da una mirada a Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente no lo soporta, seguro que lo subiste a un servidor de aplicaciones como *Glassfish, WildFly, Weblogic*  o en su defecto un contenedor de servlets como *Tomcat o Jetty* ?

Un sitio donde puedes probar tus aplicaciones de forma gratuita (tiempo limitado) es con [Jelastic](https://jelastic.com/), me parece muy bueno y fácil de utilizar.

Ahí te permiten crear y administrar tus servidores, bases de datos etc ...

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás seguro de que el servidor lo soporta?

Toma en cuenta que no cualquier servidor soporta la tecnología java, realmente dudo mucho que un servidor gratuito lo soporte, de cualquier forma si estás seguro de que el servidor lo soporta entonces verifica la instalación de glassfish y revisa si manda algún error.